# My code at a list component and href link doesn´t work

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing

```
type <li data-id="rds">
<a href="/apps/rds/" tabindex="3">
<img class="app-icon" alt="" src="/apps/rds/img/research-white.svg">
<div class="icon-loading-dark" style="display:none;"></div>
<span>
RDS App </span>
</a>
</li>
```

type here

```
driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT," RDS App ").click()
here
```

This Python-Code doesn´t work!

He shows: driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT," RDS App ").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

I want to test the rds app Link!

Answer (score 1):

Your result is a `list`, which doesn't have the click method. Try grabbing the first element of the list with this: `driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT," RDS App ")[0].click()`